# djapian based search returns no result

Tags: django

I am trying to implement a djapian based full text search for searching user 
profiles in my django site. I basically followed the following steps to build the 
indexes:

- Updated the model Profile to add the djapian indexer.
- Ran `python manage.py index --rebuild` to rebuild the indexes.

However when I try to search using the Profile indexer using:

`Profile.indexer.search("query")`
 
it does not give me any results. I do not receive any errors.
Can someone help me with this? I am a newbie w.r.t. django+djapian.
---Update 06/29/09
My indexer definition lives in models.py and is as follows:

```
class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, verbose_name=('user'))
        name = models.CharField(('name'), max_length=50, null=True, blank=True)
        about = models.TextField(('about'), null=True, blank=True)
        institution = models.CharField(('institution'),max_length=100,null=True, blank=True)
        location = models.CharField(_('location'), max_length=40, null=True, blank=True)
        website = models.URLField(_('website'), null=True, blank=True, verify_exists=False)
        def unicode(self):
            return self.user.username
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return ('profile_detail', None, {'username': self.user.username})
        get_absolute_url = models.permalink(get_absolute_url)
        class Meta:
            verbose_name = _('profile')
            verbose_name_plural = _('profiles')
```

class ProfileIndexer(djapian.Indexer):
        fields = ['name', 'about', 'institution','location']
        tags = [ ('name','name'),('about','about'),('institution','institution'),('location','location')]

```
djapian.add_index(Profile,ProfileIndexer,attach_as = 'indexer')
```

Comment: Please, give to us your indexer definition and tell where does it live in code.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. I have updated my post to answer your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that all you are missing is running

```
Profile.indexer.update()
```

at the end of models.py (you only have to do this once).

Now, I might be using an older version of Djapian than you but the following seem to work for me (end of models.py):

```
profile_indexer = djapian.Indexer(
    model=Profile,
    fields=[..., ...],
    tags=[(..., ...), (..., ...)]
)
# Run once and then comment out.
Profile.indexer.update()
```

Comment: lemonad, yup that worked. I thought the index --rebuild should have rebuilt the indexes. Thank you very much!